# Getting segmentation fault in simple program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I've been teaching myself C during the school holidays and recently tried to write a simple calculator program, which should take in two integers and perform one of four operations to them (+-*/), but whenever the first variable is assigned I get a segmentation fault / core dumped error message. I know this is to do with memory allocation and I have tried using pointers and malloc, though I suspect I am doing so incorrectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int calculate(int numberOne, int numberTwo, int operator);

int main(){

//Declaring Variables
int numberOne, numberTwo, total, operator;
int *one, *two, *tot, *op;


//Assigning Variables
printf("Integer 1: ");
scanf("%d", numberOne);
printf("\nOperator 1[+] 2[-] 3[*] 4[/] : ");
scanf("%d", operator);
printf("Integer 2: ");
scanf("\n%d", numberTwo);


//Output Calculatoin Through Function
printf("Calculation Complete: %d is the answer", calculate(numberOne, numberTwo, operator));
}

int calculate(int numberOne, int numberTwo, int operator) {

int total = 0;
do{
    switch(operator){

        case 1:
            total = numberOne + numberTwo;
            break;

        case 2:
            total = numberOne - numberTwo;
            break;

        case 3:
            total = numberOne*numberTwo;
            break;

        case 4:
            total = numberOne/numberTwo;
            break;          

        default:
            printf("Error, Invalid Operator, Please Enter A New One: ");
            scanf("%d", operator);
        }
}while(total ==0);

return total;
}
```

Comment: Cheers guys, it totally slipped my mind that I had to pass the address and not the value

Comment: As ever, please **enable compiler warnings** which (MSVC) would have given *"warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'numberOne' used"*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
scanf("%d", numberOne);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &numberOne);   //%d expects a pointer to int argument
```

and likewise.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d", numberOne);
           ^ %d expects int * not int
```

So pass address of `int` variable in all the `scanf` statements.